# OSX Today Extension without containing app

Tags: macos, osx-today-widget

I'm not understanding if a containing app is needed alongside a Today Extension for OSX. I have a very simple and straightforward widget, it does not need nor rely on a main or containing app. With that said, how can I create an Today Extension without a containing app.

What I have so far is that I have a blank app with a today extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a today extension without having an app. They don't work that way. All iOS app extensions are just that-- extensions to an app. There must be an app, and it must do something to be accepted into the app store (Apple rejects apps for "minimal functionality"). Extensions cannot exist on iOS outside of an app bundle, until or unless Apple decides to change things in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I'm assuming because of the similarities, this is applicable to OSX. So a user would have to download and start my main app to be able to get use of the extension. Wonder if I'm breaking the rules if I make a container app that has no use outside of instantiating the widget/extension, basically a blank app that just states "Thanks for downloading. Your extension is ready to be used".

Comment: Your app doesn't have to be running for an extension to appear. A blank app with a message is very likely to be rejected by the app store.

Comment: This question was for MacOS not iOS. The Apple Docs explicitly state that this is allowed for MacOS (though not iOS, as you stated).

Comment: When I answered, the question included the `ios8-today-widget` tag in addition to the `macos` tag, so it wasn't completely clear what was intended. I should have taken that into account though.

Answer (score 0):

A container app is not needed. Read up the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1) on it. It says:

> To deliver an OS X app extension, it’s recommended that you submit your containing app to the App Store, but it’s not required.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to specifically do that? It seems like you must create regular containing app before being able to create an extension target.

Comment: This is also very confusing to me. It seems like there must be a containing app, I did not find a way to create the extension without an app. How would I submit an extension without the containing app?

Comment: The paragraphs following the quoted paragraph make it clear that this simply means you can distribute your extension (and the required containing app) outside of the App Store. However, the extension still requires a containing app.